# Tableau map tooltip not displaying average reference line

Tags: tooltip, tableau-api

I created a chart visualising the cost of living in different cities and entered a line indicating the average. When integrating this sheet into the tooltip of my map, the line is not representing the average anymore but the actual cost of living for each city. I have been trying a lot but can't seem to figure it out. Thankful for any tip!

[image: Screenshot 1: chart,]
[image: Screenshot 2: map]
[image: Screenshot 3: customisations for editing reference line]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the tooltip, triggered by the click/hover, is taking into consideration just a city at once, and so the average value is equal to the sum of that specific city: you're running average on just one city.

In order to compute the correct reference value you should create a calculated field like this using LOD:

```
{ FIXED : SUM([Cost Of Living])} / { FIXED : COUNTD([City])}
```

Then you could use that calculated field in a dual axis chart.

Doing so, since EXCLUDE acts before dimension filters, you will be able to preserve your average across City even though tooltip will trigger a filter.

Take a look at this simple example made with superstore and keep and eye on the red line (LOD v2) which relates to the calulated field above.

[image]

As you can see there's also a blue line which relates to the previous calculated field I wrote (LOD v1):

```
{ EXCLUDE [State] : AVG(  { FIXED [State] : SUM([Sales])})}
```

Once we move to our main worksheet triggering the viz in tooltip, you'll see that the red value still keep the correct value calculated on all data, while the blue value is taking into consideration just data according to filter.

[image]

In fact FIXED is the only LOD calculus which act before the dimension filters and it's able to bypass the filtering triggered by the tooltip.

Comment: Hi Fabio, thanks a lot for your help, unfortunately, it still doesn't work even though I created the calculated field like you suggested and used it as a value for the reference line. In the tooltip, the line still shows the city value instead of the average, any other idea?

Comment: I used the first LOD in your answer and set it as the value for the average line, it worked!  Thanks a lot!

Comment: could you please accept the answer in order to mark this thread as closed? tnx

Comment: How do I do that? Can't find the button

Comment: You should see a V sign next to up/down vote indicator for my answer... once clicked it's should turn green ;-)